# Incorrect snapshot length returned for a specific playlist

Tags: javascript, spotify, spotify-app

I have a problem when using this spotify playlist spotify:user:juan20150:playlist:5rl5QaWjWtEPv9a057w3qc

This is the first playlist I've seen which has this problem.
The snapshot length returned is 290, but when I do snapshot.loadAll, it returns only 289 tracks.

Any idea why it would happen?

```
    var playlist = models.Playlist.fromURI("spotify:user:juan20150:playlist:5rl5QaWjWtEPv9a057w3qc");
playlist.load('tracks').done(function() {

      playlist.tracks.snapshot().done(function(snapshot) {
        console.log("snapshot length " , snapshot.length);
        $i=0;
        snapshot.loadAll('name').each(function(track) {


            console.log("i=" , i++);


        });
    });

});
```

Results:

snapshot length  290 
i = 289 (at the end)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you started at zero, and post-incremented.  If the playlist was length 3, it would print

```
0
1
2
```

for the 3 tracks.

---

**Update trying it myself**
To start with, it helps to put actual code not pseudo code.  I threw your code in my app and it didn't work.  Once I fixed it, it printed from 0 to 288.  So, I removed `.each` and put in `.done` and it didn't print anything.  However, `.fail` did return something.  Unfortunately, the error is undefined.  The below:

```
require(['$api/models'], function(models) {
    var playlist = models.Playlist.fromURI("spotify:user:juan20150:playlist:5rl5QaWjWtEPv9a057w3qc");
    playlist.load('tracks').done(function() {

    playlist.tracks.snapshot().done(function(snapshot) {
        console.log("snapshot length " + snapshot.length);
        var i=0;
        snapshot.loadAll('name')
            //.each(function(t) { console.log(i++); })
           .done(function(snap_tracks) { console.log("loaded tracks length " + snap_tracks.length); })
           .fail(function(track, error) { console.log(error + ". " + track.length); });
        });

    });
});
```

outputs:

```
14:39:15.898 I [sp://67456db3aaa5a1c25a619472cdb2cbc3f52da3ed.album-radio/js/alb
umradio.js:507] snapshot length 290
14:39:16.236 I [sp://67456db3aaa5a1c25a619472cdb2cbc3f52da3ed.album-radio/js/alb
umradio.js:512] undefined. 290
```

My best guess is that you have a song in there that is no longer accessible (licensing dispute or something).

Comment: First output is 1 and last is 289. I'm sure there are only 289 tracks returned. If I use any other playlist, it returns correct snapshot length. This specific playlist is an exception and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Ok, I used a workaround so we can close this issue. Many thanks for your help